# how can I change value in index.html from main.js in electron?

Tags: electron

at `main.js` I got user information with **access_token** from **oauth**.

now I want to change value at index.html with user name

here, how can I send user name to `index.html`?

I know  `event.sender.send` but isn' it located at `ipcMain.on`  a result of `ipcRenderer.send`?

I want to sent some value after I got **access_token**

thanks

Comment: check out [`executeJavaScript`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your index.html page is just the main page of your renderer process and isn't an external page that you're hosting in a `<webview>`, you can just send the value to the renderer and have it change whatever it needs to change in your index.html:

index.html:

```
<p id="myParagraph"></p>
<script> require("./renderer.js"); </script>
```

main.js:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...});
mainWindow.loadFile("./index.html");
// ... later we get the `accessToken`
mainWindow.webContents.send("got-access-token", accessToken);
```

renderer.js:

```
ipcRenderer.on("got-access-token", (event, accessToken) => {
    document.getElementById("myParagraph").innerText = accessToken;
});
```